# Is it possible to erase just the end of a line in Python without clearing the whole page?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I'm trying to make a snake game and when I use this loop:

```
while game_on is True:
    for item in segments:
         item.forward(20)
```

to move these snake segments (turtles),

```
snake1 = Turtle()
snake1.shape("square")
snake1.color("seagreen")

snake2 = Turtle()
snake2.shape("square")
snake2.color("medium seagreen")
snake2.penup()
snake2.setposition(-20, 0)


snake3 = Turtle()
snake3.shape("square")
snake3.color("spring green")
snake3.penup()
snake3.setposition(-40, 0)


segments = [snake1, snake2, snake3]`
```

it creates a cute little bopping moving animation thing.
I want it to look like the segments are connected by a string (just a basic line) as they bop which holds them together, but I need to be able to draw a line with the first segment and erase it with the last one. I can't seem to find an erase function in python on the web. All I can find is clear() and people recommending penup() so the line isn't drawn in the first place.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Just do not draw the last line. Even if you figure out how to erase it, it makes far more sense not to draw it in the first place. Also, if turtle works like other graphics engines. There is no "erase". "Erase" happens by removing the thing that you do not want from the display list, so it can't be drawn. It's more of a "stop drawing this" than "erase this", situation.

Answer (score -1):

Don't create multiple turtles to create your snake - it will prevent smooth animation.

Here is an example that should work well:

```py
def create_snake():
    snake_tail = []
    snake_head.color('white')
    snake_head.shape('square')
    snake_head.setheading(0)
    snake_head.pensize(11)
    snake_head.pencolor('white')
    snake_head.turtlesize(.5)

    # create tail #############
    snake_head.forward(steps * 3)
    x_pos = snake_head.pos()[0]
    y_pos = snake_head.pos()[1]
    heading = snake_head.heading()

    # create tail
    for segment in range(0, 3):
        x_pos -= steps
        snake_tail.append([[x_pos, y_pos], heading])

    # create tail end for cleanup #
    x_pos -= steps
    tail_end.shape('square')
    tail_end.turtlesize(.5)
    tail_end.hideturtle()
    tail_end.pencolor('black')
    tail_end.shape('square')
    tail_end.pensize(13)
    tail_end.pendown()
    tail_end.setposition(x_pos, y_pos)
    tail_end.setheading(heading)
    return snake_tail
```